# change color of title in html

Tags: html, colors, titlebar

Is there any way which I could change the font color of title in HTML itself ? 
I tried this

```
<style>
    title {color:red}
</style>
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: you cannot control presentation of page title

Comment: so, I cannot do anything on title section.

Answer (score 0):

The `<title></title>` defines the Name of your HTML-document. As it only shows in the title bar of your Browser and in search engines there is no way you can style it.

Comment: `And if you could edit it, it needs to look like this` can you give details why it should be inlined vs defined in style tag?

Comment: Sorry. I read the code in the question not correctly. Gonna edit my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen any styling available for the title **text**, However you can certainly change the color of your title bar in some browsers and mobile devices. use the following meta tags to achieve this.

for Chrome, Firefox and Opera:
    
for Windows phone devices:

```
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color content="COLOR_HEX_CODE">
```

for iPhone devices and safari you can only use the following:

1. black

```
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

2. default

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
```

3. translucent black

```
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```